# Why doesn't this regular expression work in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

**EDIT:** It was some issue with Notepad++'s regex engine. The regex worked fine in Python.

I'm working in Notepad++. I tried to make a regexp that would transform this (if you're curious, it's a Spanish guide for a game):

> *Acero: En la Estatua de Gabomba
>   **Absorbe PV de un enemigo

To this:

> ====Acero====
>   *En la Estatua de Gabomba
>   *Absorbe PV de un enemigo

I came up with this, but it doesn't match the text:

```
\*([^:]+): ([\w ]+)\n\*\*([^\n]+)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This matches in TextMate on Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe it’s an issue with the line breaks. Did you try Windows’ `\r\n` instead?

Comment: @robert: Yeah, I got it to work in Python, it seems to be an issue with Notepad++. I don't know why the answer that was here was deleted, but oh well. Thanks.

Comment: Please make a proper answer and accept it, or we'll have to clean this question away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Notepad++ cannot find line breaks in regex mode. You'll have to replace the line breaks with, say, `|`, in extended mode, apply the regex on your new string, then replace the `|`s with line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is correct. Try to search for `\*([^:]+): ([\w ]+)` and `\*\*([^\n]+)` separately and it will match.

It is just that Notepad++ does not support multiline regular expressions (because Scintilla doesn't). Note that there are two different search dialogs available: Ctrl+F shows the builtin dialog, Ctrl+R shows TextFX's dialog which has more options. But TextFX doesn't support multiline search either.

Answer (score 0):

As another option to the above 2 answers, [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/download/#downloads) supports POSIX regular expression syntax (including multiline).

To set TextPad to use POSIX: Configure -> Preferences -> Editor -> "Use POSIX regular expression syntax"

I prefer Notepad++ myself after using TextPad for many years, but always keep TextPad on my system for multiline regular expressions and a few other things it does well.